# Liouville property in the Bost theorem on foliations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, foliations, positive-characteristic

Let $X$ be a smooth algebraic variety over a number field $K$, and let $\mathcal{F}$ be an involutive coherent subsheaf of the tangent bundle. After a pullback to $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathcal{F}_\mathbb{C}$ gives a (singular) foliation on $X_\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{C})$ by integrating it. The integral submanifolds are called leaves.

In 2001, Bost published a paper,
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10240-001-8191-3,
in which he proves a criterion when a leaf through a given point is an algebraic subvariety. For all leaves together it can be stated this way:

All leaves of $\mathcal{F}$ are algebraic if and only if all reductions of $\mathcal{F}$ modulo $p$ are $p$-closed, and each leaf has an open subset satisfying the Liouville property: every plurisubharmonic function on the space bounded from above is constant.

My question is about this Liouville property.

$\textbf{ Do leaves of foliations always satisfy the Liouville property?}$

In the paper, Bost gives examples of classes of spaces satisfying the property, but they are not concrete enough (for me) to use the criterion. So, I am asking the very concrete question:

$\textbf{Do leaves of (algebraic) foliations on $\mathbb{P}^n$ satisfy the Liouville property?}$

Where by an algebraic foliation I mean a foliation given by a coherent algebraic subsheaf of the tangent bundle of the projective space.

Comment: For instance, if a leaf $F$ of a foliation (say in $\mathbb P^n$) is open in its Zariski closure, then any psh function of $F$ which is bounded from above extends to a psh function on $\bar F$, hence is constant since $\bar F$ is compact.

Comment: @Henri but this assumption about being open in its Zariski closure is exactly being algebraic.